# Como formatar as.numeric() um número com vírgula no R?

Tags: r

Tenho um `dataframe` com números separados por vírgula mas que estão no formato `integer` mas preciso alterar para `numeric`.

Ao usar a função `as.numeric(MEU_NUMERO)` o número fica distorcido.

Comment: Por favor dê um exemplo de `MEU_NUMERO`. Essa é uma coluna do data.frame com *"números separados por vírgula"*? Note que se os números já são de classe `"integer"`, o mais provável é **não ser necessário mudar** para `"numeric"`.

Answer (score -1):

Solução:

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", MEU_NUMERO, fixed = TRUE))
```